# How many times is the print statement executed?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

Hello,
     I've gotten far on this exercise, with the following insight:

Here is a matrix of examples (vertical-axis is n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8; horizontal-axis is k=1,2,3,4)

```
1: 1  1   1   1    
2: 2  3   4   5    
3: 3  6  10  15    
4: 4 10  20  35    
5: 5 15  35  70    
6: 6 21  56 126    
7: 7 28  84 210    
8: 8 36 120 330
```

Now, there is an obvious pattern among the numbers, being triangular numbers, sum of triangular numbers, sum of sum of triangular numbers, and so on. My question is:

Can you help me find closed form expressions for the sums of the entries:

1. Down the columns
2. Across the rows
3. And for general n,k?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern you notice (Triangular numbers, sums, etc.) can be found in Pascal's triangle:
[image: triangle]

A little bit of reasoning, along with the knowledge that the $k$th item in the $n$th row of Pascal's triangle is $\binom{n}{k}$ should lead you to a solution just by pattern-finding. The logic behind the solution is below:

To find my solution, I thought of the problem like a list of $k$ levels, where you start at any number from $1$ to $n$ and you decrease that number each time. It is helpful to think of adding an extra level on either side, so that the two sides are fixed. You add an $n$ at the beginning, since you can't start higher than that, and you add a $1$ at the end, since you can't end lower than that. Then you can represent one print statement as a string $i_1-i_2-i_3\ldots i_{k-1}-i_k$. In each new level of loop, you may or may not decrease your number. Then you can do (for n=3,k=3) $(3)-3-3-3-(1)$ or $(3)-3-2-1-(1)$. Then you can use stars and bars [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) [(2)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html), with $n$ 'stars' (downward movements) and $k$ 'bars' (dividers; the numbers/dashes between the jumps). Thus, you get $\binom{k+n-1}{k}$ print statements.

For example, the following python code runs for the case $n=5,k=3$:

```
>>> x=0
>>> n=5
>>> for i_1 in range(1,n+1):
...   for i_2 in range(1,i_1+1):
...     for i_3 in range(1,i_2+1):
...       x+=1
...       print n,"-",i_1,"-",i_2,"-",i_3,"-",1
... 
5 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1
5 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 1
5 - 2 - 2 - 1 - 1
5 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 1
5 - 3 - 1 - 1 - 1
5 - 3 - 2 - 1 - 1
5 - 3 - 2 - 2 - 1
5 - 3 - 3 - 1 - 1
5 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 1
5 - 3 - 3 - 3 - 1
5 - 4 - 1 - 1 - 1
5 - 4 - 2 - 1 - 1
5 - 4 - 2 - 2 - 1
5 - 4 - 3 - 1 - 1
5 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1
5 - 4 - 3 - 3 - 1
5 - 4 - 4 - 1 - 1
5 - 4 - 4 - 2 - 1
5 - 4 - 4 - 3 - 1
5 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 1
5 - 5 - 1 - 1 - 1
5 - 5 - 2 - 1 - 1
5 - 5 - 2 - 2 - 1
5 - 5 - 3 - 1 - 1
5 - 5 - 3 - 2 - 1
5 - 5 - 3 - 3 - 1
5 - 5 - 4 - 1 - 1
5 - 5 - 4 - 2 - 1
5 - 5 - 4 - 3 - 1
5 - 5 - 4 - 4 - 1
5 - 5 - 5 - 1 - 1
5 - 5 - 5 - 2 - 1
5 - 5 - 5 - 3 - 1
5 - 5 - 5 - 4 - 1
5 - 5 - 5 - 5 - 1
>>> x
35
```

$35=\binom{5+3-1}{3}=\binom{7}{3}$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this condensed answer. Could you clarify the iterations and the steps?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding an extra level on either side, so that the two sides are fixed" and "you can represent one print statement as a string i_1-i_2-i_3...i_(k-1)-i_k?"? I'm sorry, I just want to understand this as clearly as possible before I award the bounty to someone! I will be pushing for thorough explanations

Comment: Thanks. Could you please clarify by showing me a sample of iterations for each line and column, in the sample matrix? I can't get 56 for N=6, K=3, even by hand.

Comment: Thank you. This is **EXACTLY** what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Try induction. The code inside the $i$th loop is repeated $n - i + 1$ times.

Comment: No, the code in the $j$th loop is repeated $i_{j-1}$ times.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard "stars and bars" problem.

For given $n\geq1$ and $k\geq1$ we have to count the number of $k$-tuples $(i_1,\ldots,i_k)$ such that
$$1\leq i_k\leq i_{k-1}\leq\ldots\leq i_2\leq i_1\leq n\ .$$
Each such $k$-tuple can be encoded as a $0$-$1$-sequence of length $n+k-1$ as follows: Begin by writing $n-1$ ones, or bars $|$, leaving enough space between them. These bars create $n$ spaces between them and at the ends. The spaces represent the numbers $1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $n$. For each $i_j$ we write a $0$ into the space corresponding to its value, making a total of $k$ zeros. Conversely: Given a $0$-$1$-sequence with exactly $n-1$ ones and $k$ zeros we can immediately read off the sequence $(i_1,\ldots,i_k)$ so encoded.

There are
$${n+k-1\choose k}$$
such sequences, and this is also the number of times the print command is executed in the quoted program.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please clarify by showing me a sample of iterations for each line and column, in the sample matrix?

Comment: @Abhishek Mallela: I have edited my answer slightly and hope its obvious now. I don't understand your matrix.